# PHP printf() function outputs nothing

Tags: php, mysql, printf

My code runs without errors but produces no output when I am expecting some.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
   $result = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT * FROM `tickets`");
   while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result));
   {
   printf ("<tr>
       <td><a href='/admin/ticket.php?ticket=%s'>%s</a></td>
       <td>%s</td><td>%s</td>
       <td>%s</td><td>%s</td>
       <td>%s</td><td>%s</td>
       <td>%s</td><td>%s</td>
       <td>%s</td><td>%s</td>
       <td><a href='/admin/history.php?id=%s'><img src='/admin/img/doc.png' alt=''></a></td></tr>",
       $myrow['id'],
       $myrow['id'],
       $myrow['sla'],
       $myrow['category'],
       $myrow['date'],
       $myrow['time'],
       $myrow['vendor'],
       $myrow['mark'],
       $myrow['model'],
       $myrow['status'],
       $myrow['description'],
       $myrow['modified'],
       $myrow['id']);

   }

?>
```

Could you tell, in what place I screwed? The query returns a non-empty result, the data in the database are available, and fields are named correctly, and connection is correct ...
Here is the DB structure:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sla` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `vendor` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mark` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `timespent` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;
```

Comment: No output? Are you sure? have you checked source code?

Comment: Yes, I did, there are just empty <td> </td> cells

Comment: You have an extra `;` on the ` while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result))` line. It makes the `while()` loop through the resultset doing nothing with the rows. The subsequent `printf()` uses `$myrow` which is `NULL` and produces some HTML code but nothing visible on the browser.

Comment: you used `%s` as a placeholder for all your values, including the ones that expect integers, e.g 'id'. Try changing those to `%d`;

Comment: @mikeO. the values come from the database as strings. Converting them to numbers just to render them back into a string doesn't help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a `;` at the end of your while statement, remove this and the code will work.